# Отправить письмо на емайл

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Есть такая вот форма, в которой можно написать свои мысли и отправить их на электронный адрес фирмы:

```
<form id="contact-form">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  <p>Dear NATURA team,</p>
  <p>My
    <label for="your-name">name</label> is
    <input type="text" name="your-name" id="your-name" minlength="3" placeholder="(your name here)" required> and</p>

  <p>my
    <label for="email">email address</label> is
    <input type="email" name="your-email" id="email" placeholder="(your email address)" required>
  </p>

  <p> I have a
    <label for="your-message">message</label> for you,</p>

  <p>
    <textarea name="your-message" id="your-message" placeholder="(your msg here)" class="expanding" required></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">
      <svg version="1.1" class="send-icn" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 100 36" enable-background="new 0 0 100 36" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M100,0L100,0 M23.8,7.1L100,0L40.9,36l-4.7-7.5L22,34.8l-4-11L0,30.5L16.4,8.7l5.4,15L23,7L23.8,7.1z M16.8,20.4l-1.5-4.3
    l-5.1,6.7L16.8,20.4z M34.4,25.4l-8.1-13.1L25,29.6L34.4,25.4z M35.2,13.2l8.1,13.1L70,9.9L35.2,13.2z" />
      </svg>
      <small>send</small>
    </button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Не понимаю куда необходимо вставить адрес фирмы, чтобы письмо отправилось. 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, раз речь о Rails, то, наверное, вы [захотите использовать ActionMailer (гайд)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Чтобы отослать письмо, надо сделать эндпойнт, который будет принимать форму и отправлять письмо:

- Сделать класс мэйлера, который будет заниматься отсылкой писем. Настроить на свой вкус. Адрес, на который будет отправляться письмо, можно указать массой способов: можно в объявлении класса мэйлера (параметр `to`), а можно в коде его использующем.
- Сделать или выбрать существующий контроллер, в котором разместить экшн, который будет отправлять письмо.
- Прописать в `routes.rb`, по какому пути и с каким методом (полагаю, `POST`) будет уходить форма и какой экшн при этом будет вызываться (вышеописанный).
- Очевидно, этот же путь и метод указать и в форме.

---

Это как принято в Rails. Можно чуть облегчить решение (на первый пункт), если отказаться от ActionMailer и использовать просто [гем `mail`](https://github.com/mikel/mail) прямо в контроллере. Как указать в нём адрес получателя, можно узнать из [секции **Usage**](https://github.com/mikel/mail#usage).